# video.js.map throwing a 404 (Not Found)

Tags: video.js

Playing around with the newest video.js today, I'm noticing that video.js.map is showing up as  a 404 when putting the video.js script into a site that I'm working on.

I don't see a source map file in the initial distribution, but it doesn't throw this error locally, only when I put it on a server.

Ideas as to solving?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have a few options when you don't have access to a [source map](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/sourcemaps/):

- Ignore the message. It generaly only gets thrown when your dev tools are open.
- Remove the reference in the original file. These are the last characters (comments) at the end of the file.
- Generate a source map yourself when you have access to the source code. For `video.js`, it can be generated from `video.dev.js`.
- Use a public CDN version which might not link to the source map.

There also is a [discussion on GitHub](https://github.com/videojs/video.js/issues/650) about this topic.

Answer (score 0):

I get the same error, everything should still work though. I think it's an html5 or browser bug

Answer (score 0):

I was seeing this as well, but only in my log files.  I was getting three multi-line entries (failures) every time a video was played in my production.log in a RoR site.  It was really bulking up my .log file.  More info on @smhg's 2nd bullet (remove references).  I'm using video.js 5.4.6 along with some vpad-vast plugin stuff - I could see all three files referenced in my .log file.  Your mileage may vary.

Edit **video.js** and remove the following entry on line 19694:

```
//# sourceMappingURL=video.js.map
```

(for vpaid-vast plugin only...)

Edit **videojs_5.vast.vpaid.min.js** and remove this line from the very end:

```
//# sourceMappingURL=videojs_5.vast.vpaid.min.js.map
```

Edit **videojs.vast.vpaid.min.css** and remove this line from the very end:

```
/*# sourceMappingURL=videojs.vast.vpaid.min.css.map */
```

The entries are no longer appearing in my log file and the player works fine.

Hope it helps!